# Compiling C program from a second hard drive - stdio.h not found

Tags: c, linux-mint

I am on Linux Mint 16 and I am trying to execute a C file on a 2nd hard drive. When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
hello.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
#include <stdio.h>
```

How can I compile this C file on the 2nd hard drive?

Comment: You fix your include paths.

Comment: It can't find where the stdio.h is on your harddrive you have to fix the location in the IDE settings.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to make sure the header files are installed.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but rather how to set up Linux Mint for compiling.

Comment: In Linux distributions, the compiler is usually gcc. gcc does not care where your code lives; it knows where it is installed and where to look for its header files. Linux does not have "drives"; it has mounted volumes in a single tree. There is no such thing in Linux as `\some\include\path` not being found because you're in the D: drive, and that path is supposed to be `C:\some\include\path`.

Comment: Thanks. Mark's solution by installing build-essentials worked for me. I appreciate your helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used Mark's solution by installing build-essentials solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to make sure the header files are installed.  I did it and worked !

Comment: Avoid things like 'Thanks' and 'best regards'. Also the accepted answer is one of the comments. Avoid litterally copying and pasting the coments.